# Cray pointer of non-first element for use in malloc

Tags: pointers, fortran, fortran77, cray-pointers

I am attempting to modernize some old code that was written in Fortran 77. Eventually, my goal is to have it be F90+ compliant, but for now I'm still trying to understand bits and pieces of it.

I've already added `implicit none` and explicitly specified every variable, removed 90% of the `goto` statements, made the loops cleaner, and re-organized a lot of other things. My current problem is that I don't fully understand how cray pointers are used to allocate memory. For example, I see something like:

```
integer :: nx1, nz
integer :: x1,  z
pointer ( ptr_x1, x1(1)   )
pointer ( ptr_z,  z(1000) )

...

ptr_x1 = proprietary_malloc(nx1*SIZEOF_INTEGER)
ptr_z  = proprietary_malloc(nz *SIZEOF_INTEGER)

...

proprietary_free(ptr_x1)
proprietary_free(ptr_z)
```

Note that the `proprietary_malloc` is supposed to be a wrapper of `c`'s `malloc` with some basic internal memory checking. I am quite confident that the code *should* be calling `free` before exiting (the original F77 code simply doesn't... yikes), so I've added that myself into the example above.

If I understand correctly, after the first `malloc` statement, `x1` can be used as an array of `nx1` integers. But what about `z` after the second statement? Can someone clearly explain to me how this allocates memory dynamically? I'm much more used to `allocate` or `c++` `new` statements...

I'm compiling with `ifort` in case you need that information. Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is not really a Fortran 77 issue, Cray pointers have never been standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Short answer] I think `z` can be used as an array of `nz` integers, and if we translate the original code faithfully, it seems OK to allocate them as

```
integer, allocatable :: x1(:), z(:)
allocate( x1( nx1 ), z( nz ) )
```

Because the index of `z` in the original code may run up to 1000, it is probably safer to make sure that `nz >= 1000`.

[Long answer] According to these pages ([1](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5263/aevmr/index.html), [2](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Cray-pointers.html), [3](http://docs.cray.com/books/S-3692-51/html-S-3692-51/fvbalchri.html), [4](https://www.ibiblio.org/pub/languages/fortran/ch2-16.html)), the declaration like `pointer( ptr, a( n1, n2, ... ) )` tells the compiler to access memory starting from `ptr` as `a( 1:n1, 1:n2, ... )`; i.e., `n1`, `n2`, ... represent the array dimensions rather than starting indices. In the following example, all of `a(1)`, `b(1)`, `c(1)`, `d(1)` are mapped to `pool(3)`

```
program main
    implicit none
    integer pool( 5 )

    integer :: a, b, c, d
    pointer ( p, a( 5 ) ), ( p, b( 10 ) ), ( p, c( * ) ), ( p, d( 1 ) )

    pool = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]

    p = loc( pool( 3 ) )

    print *, "a: ", a( 1:5 )
    print *, "b: ", b( 1:5 )
    print *, "c: ", c( 1:5 )
    print *, "d: ", d( 1:5 )
end
```

so giving (with `gfortran -fcray-pointer`)

```
a:            3           4           5           0   275788968
b:            3           4           5           0   275788968
c:            3           4           5           0   275788968
d:            3           4           5           0   275788968
```

Indeed, the association rule for Cray pointer seems very similar to that of dummy arguments, for example:

```
program main
    implicit none
    integer pool( 5 )

    pool = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]

    call sub( pool(3), pool(3), pool(3), pool(3) )
end

subroutine sub( a, b, c, d )
    implicit none
    integer a( 5 ), b( 10 ), c( * ), d( 1 )

    print *, "a: ", a( 1:5 )
    print *, "b: ", b( 1:5 )
    print *, "c: ", c( 1:5 )
    print *, "d: ", d( 1:5 )
end
```

which gives the same result. We note that all the `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` access memory beyond the physically allocated one (pool(1:5)), so showing garbage data for the last two elements. Also, `print *, d( 1:5 )` violates the declared size `d(1)`, which can be checked with options like `gfortran -fcheck=all ...`.

Now going back to the OP's program, `ptr_x1` and `ptr_z` are given physical addresses obtained from malloc-like routine (for `nx1` and `nz` integers), so I guess it is probably OK to allocate `x1` and `z` with these sizes, as long as `nx1` and `nz` are given proper values.

Comment: Thank you for the interesting discussion. I have confirmed your tests and they seem to match up with my results.

Comment: Furthermore, someone at my office was able to explain the reasoning behind writing `pointer ( ptr_z,  z(1000) )`. Apparently it has to do with an old-school debugger we had in the '90s. By writing 1000 there, it told the debugger that the first 1000 elements should be on the stack (and therefore accessible to the debugger) instead of on the heap. Nowadays, that's completely irrelevant so yes I should be able to rewrite it as `allocate(z(nz))` and still be able to access the information with any compiler.